# How to open an Excel file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I am trying to convert some [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) code to C#. I am new to C#. Currently I am trying to open an Excel file from a folder and if it does not exist then create it. I am trying something like the following. How can I make it work?

```
Excel.Application objexcel;
Excel.Workbook wbexcel;
bool wbexists;
Excel.Worksheet objsht;
Excel.Range objrange;

objexcel = new Excel.Application();
if (Directory("C:\\csharp\\error report1.xls") = "")
{
    wbexcel.NewSheet();
}

else
{
    wbexcel.Open("C:\\csharp\\error report1.xls");
    objsht = ("sheet1");
}
objsht.Activate();
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Please describe it since it's easier to see directly than start creating a blank project myself and then copy and paste your code.

Comment: for starts the directory part is throwing an error 'system.io.directory is a type but used like a variable"

Comment: This would have stopped that error: if(!Directory.Exists(@"C:\csharp\error report.xls"))

Comment: if (Directory("C:\\csharp\\error report1.xls") = "") should be
if (!File.Exists("C:\\csharp\\error report1.xls"))

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need to have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO).

VSTO can be selected in the Visual Studio installer under Workloads > Web & Cloud > Office/SharePoint Development.

After that create a generic .NET project and add a reference to  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` via 'Add Reference... > Assemblies' dialog.

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
```

`Missing.Value` is a special reflection struct for unnecessary parameters replacement

---

In newer versions, the assembly reference required is called `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library`. If you do not have the latest version installed you might have `Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library`, or an older version, but it is the same process to include.

[image]

Comment: @Saravanan: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx): `Object ReadOnly`. I guess you need to pass `true`.

Comment: :Please See my Question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906670/how-to-open-excel-file-in-c-sharp-winform-application-with-read-only-protection

Comment: when I add that I get error as `CS0104: 'DataTable' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.DataTable' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable'`

Comment: @coder: remove `using System.Data;` or use "`using DataTable = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable;`

Comment: @abatishchev: when I remove `using System.Data;` i get namespace error for `dataset` which I am using for another set of code..

Comment: @coder: use full name (namespace.class.name) in either case

Comment: when I write `System.Data.DataTable ObjDt = ObjPriDal.ExecuteSystem.Data.DataTable(strquery);` it gives error for `ExecuteSystem` as **DataAccessLayer does not contain a definition for `ExecuteSystem`**

Comment: @coder: you don't need it in the right expression. Use full name as you usually declare variable's type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108998/discussion-between-coder-and-abatishchev).

Comment: @abatishchev: I tried like this `var directory = Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/");
        ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc));` getting error as **cannot implicitly convert type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to Excellibrary.office.Excel.Workbook**

Comment: @abatishchev I tested your code, it's running. I'm wondering though, how is it possible to instantiate Application when it is actually an interface?

Comment: @ThomasMX: I was wondering this for a while too. Since VSO is a COM wrapper, .NET makes it possible to instantiate an interface. Each is decorated with Guid and that's how it's being read from registry and  instantiated.

Comment: See here for a full example of creating and saving an Excel file using the interop https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102523/8595398

Answer (score 62):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\test\\report.xlsx");
if(fi.Exists)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\test\report.xlsx");
}
else
{
    //file doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Certainly simpler than the accepted 2009 answer because no additional tools are needed, and it is essential a one-liner.

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for, thanks! I simplified it by just passing the fi inside the start as `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fi.ToString());`

Comment: This is by far, the most easy way to do it. Thank you

Comment: This is the best solution. However in .NET core it has to be done a bit differently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970719/1018443

Answer (score 11):

```
private void btnChoose2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog openfileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
  if (openfileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
  {
    this.btnChoose2.Text = openfileDialog1.FileName;
    String filename = DialogResult.ToString();

    var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = true;
    excelApp.Workbooks.Open(btnChoose2.Text);
  }
}
```

Comment: The excel does not show without excelApp.Visible = true. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Imports

```
 using Excel= Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
 using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;
```

Here is the code to open an excel sheet using C#.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbv = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\YourExcelSheet.xlsx");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wx = excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

    wbv.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    excel.Quit();
```

Here is a video mate on how to open an excel worksheet using C# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5Dnv0tfGv4

Answer (score 3):

For opening a file, try this:

```
objexcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\YourPath\YourExcelFile.xls",
    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,missing, missing);
```

You must supply those stupid looking 'missing' arguments. If you were writing the same code in VB.Net you wouldn't have needed them, but you can't avoid them in C#.

Comment: Unless you're using VS2010 :) Oh, and you want _Missing.Value_

Comment: `private object _value = Missing.Value;`  replace the missing with _value. And it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

you should open like this

```
        Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

source : http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm

ruden

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to help you if you say what's wrong as well, or what fails when you run it.

But from a quick glance you've confused a few things.

The following doesn't work because of a couple of issues.

```
if (Directory("C:\\csharp\\error report1.xls") = "")
```

What you are trying to do is creating a new Directory object that should point to a file and then check if there was any errors.

What you are actually doing is trying to call a function named Directory() and then assign a string to the result. This won't work since 1/ you don't have a function named Directory(string str) and you cannot assign to the result from a function (you can only assign a value to a variable).

What you should do (for this line at least) is the following

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\csharp\\error report1.xls");
if(!fi.Exists)
{
    // Create the xl file here
}
else
{
    // Open file here
}
```

As to why the Excel code doesn't work, you have to check the documentation for the Excel library which google should be able to provide for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excapp;

excapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

object misval=System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Workbook wrkbuk = new Workbook();

Worksheet wrksht = new Worksheet();

wrkbuk = excapp.Workbooks._Open(@"C:\Users\...\..._template_v1.0.xlsx", misval, misval, 
misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval);

wrksht = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wrkbuk.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a commercial application or some hobbyist / open source software?

I'm asking this because in my experience, all free .NET Excel handling alternatives have serious problems, for different reasons. For hobbyist things, I usually end up porting jExcelApi from Java to C# and using it.

But if this is a commercial application, you would be better off by purchasing a third party library, like [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.cells-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx). Believe me, it totally worths it as it saves a lot of time and time ain't free.

Answer (score 1):

For editing Excel files from within a C# application, I recently started using [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi).
I'm very satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Code :**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        textBox1.Enabled=false;

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Excell File |*.xlsx;*,xlsx";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string extn = Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName);
                if (extn.Equals(".xls") || extn.Equals(".xlsx"))
                {
                    filename = ofd.FileName;

                    if (filename != "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string excelfilename = Path.GetFileName(filename);


                        }
                        catch (Exception ew)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Errror:" + ew.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```