# Open Excel Workbook file Using Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, excel, resources, embedded-resource, excel-interop

I am using Microsoft Office Interop to open Excel files. The file is placed in a special folder from where it the Workbook code reads the file. Now, the requirement is that the Excel file can be placed anywhere. I believe the best approach is to attach the Excel file as an embedded resource. But if I attach as embedded resource how will I read the file using Excel workbook.

```
_excelapplication.Workbooks.Open(Filename: pExcelTemplatePath);
```

What is the best way to read the excel template file regardless of the location of the file?

Comment: Do you want to edit the template OR just create a new document based on it ?

Comment: Just create a new document based on it. I set the build action to Content and now I can see the file in the published folder.

Comment: regarding clickonce see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fehc36e.aspx - any further help needed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't open it directly from the embedded resources - at least not with Interop...

You will need to save it somewhere as a file - i.e. first read it from the resource (for example by `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNameOfEmbeddedExcelFile)`) and then write that stream to some location like [`ApplicationData` / `CommonApplicationData` / `LocalApplicationData` / `MyDocuments` / `CommonDocuments` from `Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

Another option would be to use a library capable of opening/editing Excel files from a stream - let me know if you need some links to libraries...

Comment: I wouldn't mind a link to those libraries, I am investigating a way to let people edit Office documents from a stream.

Comment: @BigBadOwl I think you should post a new question... esp. with some additional context like: what features do you need for "let people edit Office documents from a stream" besides being able to open from a stream ? which office formats (excel, word, powerpoint... 2003 and/or 2010)?

Answer (score 0):

First you should get stream of your resource file using this function:

```
 public static Stream GetResourceFileStream(string fileName)
            {
                Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                // Get all embedded resources
                string[] arrResources = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

                foreach (string resourceName in arrResources)
                {
                    if (resourceName.Contains(fileName))
                    {
                        return currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
```

Then you can save the stream to the file: [How do I save a stream to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file).

And open it: [How to open an Excel file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c).