# How to open Excel file with Read Only protection?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, vsto, office-interop

I have opened Excel file in my C# WinForm Application adding reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` and using DSO FRAMER CONTROL. But i want to open my excel file with read only protection.I have successfully done this for WORD Application like this

```
Word.Document wordDoc = (Word.Document)axFramerControl1.ActiveDocument;
Word.Application wordApp = wordDoc.Application;
wordDoc.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading);
```

In the same i want to do this work for Excel.But i couldn't able to protect Excel file on that way.

```
string path = "C:\\test-wb.xlsx";
axFramerControl1.Open(path, true,"excel.sheet", "", "");

Excel._Workbook excelDoc   =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)axFramerControl1.ActiveDocument;
Excel.Application excelApp =excelDoc.Application;
//What code should i write to protect Excel Workbook with read - only.
excelDoc.Protect(misval, true, misval);//It is not working.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call the`Open` method with third parameter (`ReadOnly`) = `true`.

See MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open%28v=office.11%29.aspx) :

**ReadOnly**
Optional Object. True to open the workbook in read-only mode.

Comment: :Thanks gdoron.Can you please tell where should i give that parameter in my above code that i mentioned in my question?

Comment: @Saravanan. According to the MSDN, you should open with third param true. which .Net framework do you use? .Net 4?

Comment: This helped me.  Instead however I just added the password as the 6th parameter of the Open method.

Answer (score -1):

The WorkBook class has a Protect method, similar (but not identical) to the one supported by Word. I can't find the COM/interop documentation, but the VSTO documentation covers the same ground, and the method signatures are the same:

[Protect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.protect%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Protects a workbook so that it cannot be modified.

```
public virtual void Protect (
    [OptionalAttribute] Object Password,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object Structure,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object Windows
)
```

(This all assumes that what you wanted to achieve was to protect the document, since that's what the Word code does, as opposed to opening the document read only, which is what your narrative seems to be saying, in which case, [@gdoron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8906733/15498) is more suitable