# Read excel file content in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

I want to read excel file in my C#,WPF application. which is running on  different machines having different versions of excels(some has excel-2003 while some machines have excel-2007 etc and some machines doesn't have any office installed at all). I want to read excel file content regardless of with/without any excel versions/packages installed on the target machines.

I am currently using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read data from excel file but on running my app on target machine which doesn't have any office installed, my application doesn't work.

How can I do it?
I am doing it the following way, added namespaces

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Here comes the method's body:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range range;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(_filePath);
            List<string> Folders = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;


                for (int cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                {
                    Folders.Add(((range.Cells[1, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value).ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //some error msg
            }
            finally
            {
                xlWorkBook.Close();
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
            return Folders;
        }
```

Comment: Here it comes:  what have you tried?

Comment: using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read excel file data.

Comment: "I am currently using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read data from excel file but on running my app on target machine which doesn't have any office installed, my application doesn't work" - Yep. That's expected.

Comment: As Mitch Wheat says, that's expected. Interop isn't a full set of features, it's a library to *interact* - in this case, with Office. If you don't want to install Office, you're better off using another library that natively reads the files.

Comment: Any names/ tutorials of that libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some solutions already here:

[How to open an Excel file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c)

If you are developing open source application, there are some third party libraries, so take a look at the following:

- http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/
- http://excellite.codeplex.com/
- http://excelwrapperdotnet.codeplex.com/
- http://netoffice.codeplex.com/