# How to open an excel file from VSTO plugin and get VSTO workbook?

Tags: c#, vsto, import-from-excel

I [already know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/465676/2389310) how to open file and get `Workbook` from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace. But is there a way to get `Workbook` from `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` namespace? Casting between the two does not work. I know this sound simple, but I'm stuck - all answers on SO point to `Interop` solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442981.aspx) on MSDN, the `Workbook` interface in the `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` namespace is an "extended object" which "add[s] functionality to objects that exist natively in the Word or Excel object models (called native Office objects)".

The relevant code from that page on how you can create such an extended object is:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook nativeWorkbook = 
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
if (nativeWorkbook != null)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook vstoWorkbook = 
        Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(nativeWorkbook);
}
```

Comment: Seems it works. Will accept if / when confirmed, +1 for now because it's a good track and a point I can start with.

Comment: `Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(excelApllication.Workbooks.Open(filename));` did it. Thanks.