# How to get the data from Excel into C#?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a C# program that takes some data from Excel and saves it to an SQL database. When I open the Excel file and run the program it is working successfully but if I close the Excel file and try to run the program again there is an error like:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll and Additional information=The table is
>   not true way.

So how can I solve this problem?

Here is the part of my code that errors:

```
string conexcel = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=\kisiler.xlsx;" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";

string cmd = "SELECT * FROM [Sayfa1$]";
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conexcel);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
```

adp.Fill(ds); is my error part.

Comment: Take a look at : How to open an Excel file in C#


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c

Comment: he is using excel dll but i am using oledb connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is opening an xlsx file, but using an older version of oledb provider.
Try this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=kisiler.xlsx;" + "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml";
```