# Use OldeDbConnection to read excel sheet using 9th row as the column names?

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I'm trying to read an excel sheet using oleDbConnection and OleDbDataAdapter and then filling a DataSet with that information. What i need to figure out how to do is ignore the first 8 rows in the excel sheet and read it as if the 9th row was the first row, (making the column names the values in the 9th row).

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: are you familiar with looping, counters etc.. this is actually quite simple use a loop and the key word `continue` inside that loop until a condition is met..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answered my question good.. But i figured it out on my lonesome.

I solved the problem by reading the excel sheet into a dataTable. Then removing the first 8 rows from the dataTable. then i created a second datatable, manually added the columns(use the Columns.Add command) and used a foreach(row in OGdataTable) to add all the rows to the new table.

If anybody wants more clarification on this, go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How to open an Excel file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c)

To add some input on your specific scenario: there is a Worksheet object that has a Rows attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other approaches I'd suggest to use [LinqToExcel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) you can find it on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/), this way you'll end up with a IQueryable object instead of some messy Dataset, e.g.:

Defining your entity:

```
class MyType
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

If you know the range you want to read you can do something like:

```
var excel=new ExcelQueryFactory(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    var q = from r in excel.WorksheetRange<MyType>("A9","C12")
            select r;
```

Then you can use q to filter, iterate, etc...

If you don't know how many rows are there in the file to define the range you can do something like this instead:

```
var excel=new ExcelQueryFactory(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
int rowCount=excel.WorksheetNoHeader().Count();
    var q = from r in excel.WorksheetRange<MyType>("A9","C"+rowCount)
            select r;
```