# Opening an excel file using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

My requirement is to open an excel file which is under **Attachment** folder. So I took the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c) and used **abatishchev** answer for my requirement. So I tried that in my below code.

```
public void ExportExcel()
{
   string str_lwpc_query = string.Empty;
   str_lwpc_query = "select company_name 'COMPANY NAME',Deputed_Company_Name 'DEPUTED COMPANY NAME',emp_card_no 'EMP CODE',emp_name 'EMPLOYEE NAME',LWP,'' Remarks,  " +
                    "Adj_Days Gain_Loss_LOP_Days, VAL_DAY LOP_Days_Desc, month, year from XXACL_EMP_INFO_LWP_OTDAYS_HRS_V " +
                     "where emp_type='C' and month = '3' and year = '2015' ";
    DataTable Dt_lwpc = new DataTable();
    Dt_lwpc = CF.ExecuteDT(str_lwpc_query);
    DataSet DS_lwpc = new DataSet();
    DS_lwpc.Tables.Add(Dt_lwpc);
    DS_lwpc.Tables[0].TableName = "Employee loss of pay for consultant Details";
    var directory = Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/");
    ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc));
}
```

but I get error in the last line as

> The best overloaded method match for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(string, object, object, object, ...........) has some invalid arguments

kindly suggest what is wrong

Comment: @DmitryRotay: tried got error as `cannot implicitly convert type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook an explicit conversion exists ( are you missing a cast)`

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment accidentally. You are trying to open file with Microsoft's Excel interop library - the result returned is of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook`. but are expecting result type to be of some custom library - ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook.

Comment: @DmitryRotay: so what's the solution for this ?

Comment: If you really want to use excel interop to open workbook and work with it, then you need to replace the last line with this: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc));`

Comment: i get the same error as mentioned in the question now

Comment: Ah, sorry. Lost code from my deleted comment. Try this. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls")`

Comment: It's kinda hard to make suggestions, since we don't know versions of interops and ExcelLibrary that you are using. It's also possible, that this construct will work: `ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook wb = ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook.Load(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc);` In this case you don't need previous line of code creating Excel.Application.

Comment: @DmitryRotay: so can u give me the full updated code that I will try ? currently i added ur code and getting error as `Could not load file or assembly 'Office, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Comment: Version 7.0 sounds a little outdated. Please try the latter example that I've posted with `Workbook.Load`. It's more robust if your project generally uses ExcelLibrary to work with excel documents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109003/discussion-between-coder-and-dmitry-rotay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want users of your website to open an excel file that you've created on server, than you don't need to open it there - just send it to the user. Replace the last two lines of code with this:

```
string filePath = directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls"; 
Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", 
"attachment; filename=" + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls"); 
Response.TransmitFile(filePath); 
Response.End();
```

Comment: thanks a lot Dmitry for the patience and resolving the issue step by step. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open takes a filename and a number of additional parameters, [see the MSDN documentation here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx) The CreateWorkbook method that you're calling is not returning the required arguments for Open.

Comment: so waht would be my code according to this ? kindly update

Comment: Have you tried just using `ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls"));`? If I'm understanding your code correctly, that would open the Workbook you created a few lines up.

Comment: the above code just places the file in the `attachment` folder but it doesn't opens the file

Comment: `ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls", DS_lwpc);` places the file in the attachment folder, but `ExcelLibrary.Office.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(directory + "Employee_lwpc_Details.xls"));` opens that file and assigns a local variable to it.

Comment: that's what I also know,but why it is not opening the file then ?

Comment: What do you mean by "opening the file"? The file is open, and you can access it via the local variable `wb`.

Comment: how to check whether it is open or not ? and how to access the same file ??