# How to open excel workbook from powershell for automation

Tags: .net, excel, powershell, automation

I want to open an excel workbook and read out data, do other kinds of operations, etc.  I know that I have to add an assembly reference:

```
 [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\ADDINS\Microsoft Power Query for Excel Integrated\bin\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll")
```

And then I need to instantiate an Application object.

```
$workbook = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
```

This however returns an error "A constructor was not found"
Isn't by the way Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application an interface actually? I am wondering how it can be instantiated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c) scenario.

Comment: Depending upon exactly what you need to do with the document, take a look at the [ImportExcel](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/) by Doug Finke, or use it as an ODBC data source. For certain tasks, these will be **much** faster and easier than automating Excel itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found a nice snippet which also runs a macro [here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/f/4833/t/19568976)

```
# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#open file
$FilePath = 'C:\temp\Book1.xlsm'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

#make it visible (just to check what is happening)
$excel.Visible = $true

#access the Application object and run a macro
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("Macro1")
```

Comment: in $app.Run("Macro1"), what is Macro1 referencing? A file? A variable?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer TBH I can't quite recall becaues I posted this answer a while ago. I guess it is the name of a Sub( ) in either of the macro files. See doco at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run

Comment: `$excel.Visible = $true` was really useful to make the spreadsheet visible.

Comment: Might be just me. But I need to specifiy it like this to make it work. Else i get an error about core types due to my language mode. `$excel.Application.Visible = $true`

Answer (score 23):

You need to open it as a ComObject.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
```

In that example you would have needed to define `$FilePath` as the full path to the Excel file that you are trying to open.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add the path to the variable `$FilePath` without quotes, it will open automatically:

```
$FilePath = C:\temp\tempfile.csv
```

The only problem is that if you did not properly closed the file on Excel, the next time you run it, it will open as `READ ONLY` and you have to kill the process on TASK manager.

Depending of the needs and coding, sometimes simple works the best.

Comment: A CSV file isn't an Excel file. Excel can open it, but it's just text with comma-separated values (hence the name). Native Excel XLS files are binary, defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/cd03cb5f-ca02-4934-a391-bb674cb8aa06). Newer XLSX files are ZIP containers with data in the Office Open XML standard ([ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/) and [ISO/IEC 29500:2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oi29500/1fd4a662-8623-49c0-82f0-18fa91b413b8)).

Answer (score -1):

Just let Windows take care of the hard part for you:

explorer.exe $filename

Simples :)

Comment: This works and is the simplest answer here.

Comment: the answer is most relevant to question