# Converting VBA macro to C#

Tags: c#, vba

I have a VBA macro that I am trying to convert to C#. I am having trouble linking to the excel application and using the excel commands.

Below is a piece of the code I am trying to convert.

```
Dim myExcel As Excel.Application 
Dim mySheet As Worksheet 
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim myFile As Variant

Set myExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set mySheet = myExcel.Worksheets("sheetname")
```

I have tried adding the reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` but cannot find the how a reference a particular sheet or cell in a sheet. I am trying to learn C#,

so your patience is very much appreciated along with any help.

Comment: you  reference a particular sheet or cell in a sheet in the same way regardless of vba or C# (except maybe '(' becomes '[' ). Plese show your attempt. If want you want to do is manipulate excel from C# then look at EppPlus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open an Excel file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c)

Comment: `Dim myExcel As Excel.Application`  = `Excel.Application myExcel;` & `Set myExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` = `SetmyExcel = GetObject(,, "Excel.Application");`

Comment: Is this vsto? winform?