# How can I embed an excel file within a windows form in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to display an Excel file within a Windows Form, not based with .NET, but just for a desktop application. I need to be able to save the form as a PDF in a location on users personal computer and then also print it out. I don't want the file to open a Excel sheet but for it to look like its part of the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open an Excel file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c)

Comment: I am wanting to know if there are any example projects of this ?

Comment: This may help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0d37c5a9-b086-43d3-9d34-056159263e54/embed-excel-workbook-in-windows-forms?forum=winforms

Comment: I don't want it in a web browser is there a way without

Comment: I think it's the easiest solution, you will waste less time and effort. Why don't you want to see it like this?

Comment: It'for a software which may be used where there is no acsess to Internet .... Needs to be on local desktop x

Comment: Check if this helps: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/View-and-Edit-Excel-11db98ac

Comment: I don't think the browser has any relation with the internet. I think it's only an interface. I'd suggest to run it and later, unplug the internet cable and check if it really uses the internet, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you this example:

[How to Integrate Excel in a Windows Form Application using the WebBrowser](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15760/how-to-integrate-excel-in-a-windows-form-applicati)

You can embed the Spreadsheet into a Windows Forms with that trick from [bsargos](https://www.codeproject.com/Members/bsargos).

For the export you can try this:

[iTextSharp, a .NET PDF library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp)